# Requirements for travelling to Portugal from Spain via land

Tags: covid-19, portugal

I'm an Indian citizen travelling in Spain for the last 14 days. If I was visiting Portugal by land:

- Do I need to submit a passenger locator card?
- I have a EU digital covid certificate. Do I need an antigen/PCR test as those required by air travel?

Answer (score 2):

I see conflicting information from [other sources](https://imigrante.sef.pt/en/covid-19/faqs/#1621260456638-8876f963-fd47) (maybe not updated yet), but there is this:

The requirements have recently (December 1) been [tightened](https://www.visitportugal.com/en/content/covid-19-measures-implemented-portugal).

> 2. Arriving to Portugal by Land
>
> Citizens from EU countries considered to be at low or moderate risk
> must hold a COVID EU Digital Certificate, in the form of vaccination,
> testing or recovery.
>
> Citizens from countries outside the EU and from EU countries
> considered to have a red or dark red risk level must present:
>
> - EU Covid Digital Certificate in test or recovery modes, or
> - Negative RT-PCR test performed in the last 72 hours, or
> - Rapid negative antigen test performed within the last 48 hours
>
> Information on EU countries' risk level:
> https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/covid-19/situation-updates/weekly-maps-coordinated-restriction-free-movement
>
> Cross-border workers, who carry out their professional activity within
> 30 km of the border, and workers in essential services (transport of
> goods and passengers, emergency and relief, security and emergency
> services) must present the Digital Certificate in the modalities of
> vaccination, test or recovery.
>
> Citizens from Southern African countries, namely South Africa,
> Botswana, Essuatini, Lesotho, Mozambique, Namibia and Zimbabwe in the
> last 14 days must undergo RT-PCR test (TAAN) or Rapid Antigen test
> (TRAGg) to COVID-19 and comply with 14 days of prophylactic isolation
> at home or in a place indicated by health authorities.